# Happy number out put

Tags: c#

i am doing a Happy number exercise. FYI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number
here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> happynum = new List<string>();
            Program test = new Program();
            string number = "7";
            if (test.CheckHappy(number))
            {
                happynum.Add(number);
            }

            if (happynum.Contains(number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("0");
            }

        }
        public bool CheckHappy(string num) {
            int sum = 0;
            int temp = int.Parse(num);
            while (temp != 1) {
                while (temp != 0)
                {
                    int digit = temp % 10;
                    sum += digit * digit;
                    temp = temp / 10;
                }
                temp = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

when i put a "true" happy number like 7, 1, the console print 1, but when i put something like 22, 435, it doesn't print 0
Please help !!!

Comment: You missed out this bit:  if the number is unhappy.....it loops `endlessly` in a cycle which does not include 1. So basically it never prints `0` as your got got stuck in an infinite loop. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number

Comment: @GrantWinney here is the definition of happy number : A happy number is defined by the following process. Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers.

Comment: You missed this bit from the pseudocode: `When the algorithm ends in a cycle of repeating numbers, this cycle always includes the number 4, so it is not even necessary to store previous numbers in the sequence`

Comment: All non-happy numbers follow sequences that reach the cycle:

    4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number),  if the number is unhappy the algorithm will loop endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. So basically it never prints 0 as your got got stuck in an infinite loop. However,  when the algorithm ends in a cycle of repeating numbers, this cycle always includes the number 4, so you simply have to add another `if` statement to terminate the while loop when the number is unhappy.

```
while (temp != 0)
{
    int digit = temp % 10;
    sum += digit * digit;
    temp = temp / 10;

    //You need this to stop the infinite loop 
    if (sum == 4)
          return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however it should be if(sum == 4) :D

Comment: The best solution, otherwise I was also trying to figure out what the solution for infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to find Happy or Sad Number:

```
public static string HappyOrSad(string input, char[] arr)
    {
        int result = 0;
        // Hashset to store ouput of each loop
        HashSet<int> repNumber = new HashSet<int>();

        // If number is repeated, break the loop
        while (!repNumber.Contains(result) )
        {
            int temp = 0;
            repNumber.Add(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                // Converting character array to integer
                temp += Convert.ToInt32(arr[i].ToString()) * Convert.ToInt32(arr[i].ToString());
            }                
            arr = temp.ToString().ToCharArray();
            result = temp;                
        }

        return result == 1 ? "Happy" : "Sad";
    }
```

Full program here: http://aravin.net/csharp-program-find-happy-sad-number/

Answer (score 0):

This method will return true , if given number is happy number or else it will return false. We are using set here to avoid infinite loop situation.

Input: 19

Output: true

Explanation:

1*1 + 9*9 = 82

8*8 + 2*2 = 68

6*6 + 8*8 = 100

1*1 + 0*0 + 0*0 = 1

```
     public static boolean isHappy(int n) {

          Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();

          while(n != 1) {
            int current = n;
            int sum = 0;
            while(current != 0) {
                sum += (current % 10) * (current % 10);
                current /= 10;
            }

            if(seen.contains(sum)) {
                return false;
            }

            seen.add(sum);
            n = sum;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution for python, having `O(n)` time complexity. I have used python, but the algorithm will help you get the idea.
I have used recursion to perform this operation.

**Algorithm:**

> 1. Take the variable to sum out all the digits present in the num
> 2. Loop through the digit of the number, and sum out all the digits square
> 3. Now add the sum data to the tested number itself
> 4. If the number equals 1, return true, if number equals 4 return false
> 5. Else call the function again, by passing the number having sum data

**Code:**

```
def isHappy(num: int) -> bool:
   digitSum = 0

   for i in str(num):
     # This sums up the squared of the digit
     digitSum += pow(int(i),2)

   # now pass the digitSum to the num variable itself
   num = digitSum

   if num == 1: return True
   elif num == 4: return False
   else: return isHappy(num)
```

Hope this will help you in a greater extent. If not the code, then the algorithm. Thanks [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4640209/alex) for your great algo help. Saved a lot of time